# what *first is printing here in this code?

Tags: c, pointers

please tell what `*first` is printing here

```
struct Node{
    int info;
    struct Node *next;
};

    void main()
    {
        struct Node* first=NULL;
        struct Node* second=NULL;
        struct Node* third=NULL;

        first=(struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  
        second=(struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  
        third=(struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  

        first->info=1;
        first->next=second;

            printf("*first  %d ->\n ",*first);  //6487584  ?? what is  *first is here should it be same as first->info?
            printf("first  %d ->\n",first);     //13439936
            printf("&first  %d ->\n",&first);   //6487608

                printf("&first->info  %d ->\n",&first->info); //13439936
                printf("&first->next  %d ->\n",&first->next);  //13439944

    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Aroint thee, screenshot! Please do not post pictures of text. The text itself is preferred here.

Comment: Get a better compiler. That code should spit out a displayful of warnings and errors!

Comment: And the question is: "I threw dice and got two fours. Then I looked out of the window, and saw the full moon. Why?"

Answer (score 3):

All of these

```
printf("*first  %d ->\n ",*first);
printf("first  %d ->\n",first);
printf("&first  %d ->\n",&first);
printf("&first->info  %d ->\n",&first->info);
printf("&first->next  %d ->\n",&first->next);
```

produce undefined behavior because of the mismatch between format specifier `%d` (which requires an `int` argument) and the type of the actual argument supplied to `printf`.

They don't print anything meaningful.

While your attempts to print pointer values can be salvaged by using a proper format specifier and/or a cast, printing `*first` is not salvageable. `*first` is a value of `struct Node` type. There's no appropriate format specifier in `printf` to process such value in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

Your program invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If you want to print the address of an object (the `&` operator gives the address of an object), cast the address to `(void *)` and use the `%p` specifier in `printf` like this:

```
printf("&first->info -> %p\n",(void *) &first->info);
```

If your intention was to print `info` itself, this should suffice:

```
printf("first->info -> %d\n", first->info);
```

When printing `*first` with a `%d` specifier, you are de-referencing the address contained in `first` and saying whatever that happens to be is to be printed as an `int`.

Comment: if i use %p ,in that case what is *first is printing here?

Comment: @somashekhar By `*first` you get the data that resides at the address (actually a number) contained in `first`. Then you tell `printf` that the data is actually a pointer. You won't get anything meaningful as `first` is a pointer to a struct. In fact it would be implementation defined I guess.

Comment: wholly undefined behaviour.